Compute ellipse semi-axis from conic matrix
I've an ellipse expressed as conic matrix $C$, this ellipse is translated and rotated what is the procedure to compute the semi-axis length? The procedure I'm following now, is the following expressed in python code:
# Extract the conic coefficients
# NOTE: C is the 3x3 conic matrix
A = C[0, 0]
B = 2 * C[0, 1]
C_ = C[1, 1]
D = 2 * C[0, 2]
E = 2 * C[1, 2]
F = C[2, 2]
        
# Calculate the center of the ellipse
M = np.array([[A, B / 2], [B / 2, C_]])
rhs = np.array([-D / 2, -E / 2])
center = np.linalg.solve(M, rhs)
        
# Calculate the rotation of the ellipse in degrees
theta_rad = 0.5 * np.arctan2(B, A - C_)
theta_deg = np.rad2deg(theta_rad)
        
eigenvalues, _ = np.linalg.eig(M)
positive_eigenvalues = eigenvalues[eigenvalues > 0]
semiaxes = np.sqrt(1 / positive_eigenvalues[:2])

The center and the rotation are correct but the semi-axis result is much bigger than the one I would expect (I've the correct result), what am I missing?
An example of conic C that i've is:
\begin{bmatrix}
5.32395964 \times 10^{-7} & 1.75881625 \times 10^{-8} & -6.94656059 \times 10^{-4} \\
1.75881625 \times 10^{-8} & 6.71611473 \times 10^{-7} & -2.44483115 \times 10^{-4} \\
-6.94656059 \times 10^{-4} & -2.44483115 \times 10^{-4} & 1.00000000 \times 10^{0}
\end{bmatrix}
Thank to everyone in advance.

This is an empty conic over the reals. With $F=-1$ you get an ellipse. You need $F$ to be used in your script...

@whatamidoing unfortunately thei are not correct.

@Jan-Magnus Økland can you elaborate a little bit more?

Varying $F$ for what would be an ellipse $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ there is an $F=F'$ for which it is a point conic. The $F$ on one side of this $F'$ give ellipses and on the other side give empty conics. Your code gives the semi-axes of the ellipse for which $F$ gives rise to $-1$ in the rotated.

IIRC you'd have to scale by something like the determinant of your three by three matrix $C$ or the ratio of the first two by two minor to this and check that it has a point, i.e. that it is not like $x^2+y^2+1=0.$

From this answer.

Assume WLOG that $A>0$ (otherwise multiply the equation by $-1$). We have
$$
\left[\matrix{x\\ y}\right]^T\left[\matrix{A & B\\ B & C}\right]\left[\matrix{x\\ y}\right]+2\left[\matrix{D\\ E}\right]^T\left[\matrix{x\\ y}\right]+F=0.
$$
After completing the square we get
$$
\left(\left[\matrix{x\\ y}\right]+\left[\matrix{A & B\\ B & C}\right]^{-1}\left[\matrix{D\\ E}\right]\right)^T\left[\matrix{A & B\\ B & C}\right]\underbrace{\left(\left[\matrix{x\\ y}\right]+\left[\matrix{A & B\\ B & C}\right]^{-1}\left[\matrix{D\\ E}\right]\right)}_{={\bf x'}}=\\
=\underbrace{\left[\matrix{D\\ E}\right]^T\left[\matrix{A & B\\ B & C}\right]^{-1}\left[\matrix{D\\ E}\right]-F}_{=\alpha^2}.
$$

Your code produces the semi-axes if $A>0$ (which it is) and $\alpha^2$ should happen to be $1$.
